# How to iterate a list of WebElements and store the values and to perform DB Comparision

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

From UI I have to read the below values (I have given example values)

- EmployeeID : 100
- First name : abc
- Last name : XYZ
- Joining date : 22-Aug-2015
- Gender : Male
- Phone Number : 10908333

I have to compare this with data from the database. The database stores the data as a Key value pair like (Field_Name) and (Field_Value).

I am using the following code to extract the list values:

```
List<WebElement> payLoads = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='payloadAndCharts']/d‌​iv/div[1]/div")); 
Iterator<WebElement> itr = payLoads.iterator(); 
while(itr.hasNext()) 
{ 
  System.out.println(itr.next().getText());
}
```

I am using split by : (colon) to extract the field name and field value, and save into hasp map so I can compare with the DB field name and field value.

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: To suggest a better approach we need to have your approach. Have you implemented some code already?. Also please specify the programming language you're using.

Comment: Iterating a list and comparing values is a programming question...

Comment: I have implemented below code to print values using Java code 
List<WebElement> payLoads = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='payloadAndCharts']/div/div[1]/div"));
  Iterator<WebElement> itr = payLoads.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(itr.next().getText());

Comment: @praveencn did that print what you were expecting?

Comment: Yeh its printing the expected but how can I validate with the DB. In DB its a Key value pair like (Field_Name) and (Field_Value).From UI I have to split by : (colon) and save in to hasp map and compare with DB.Is this approach is correct ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add relevant information, rather than putting it in the comments. I have made the edits for you this time.

Comment: To use any library, you need to become competent programmer in your chosen language. Get a book or online course and learn loops, data structures etc. Once you are competent programmer, these problems are trivial and solutions are obvious. IMHO this is not a forum to teach  programming basics - correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So your test would consisit of three parts

1. **Fetch the user fields from UI**. To make the effective fetching code you have to examine the structure of html that represents your user data. The same would affect the most appropriate data structure to store. I would better implement a class that would represent the data you have on your UI. Also I would implement my own `equals()` method to make assertions easier.

Example:

```
class Employee{

    int employeeId;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    // ...
    // other fields;
    // getters
    // setters
    // constructors

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(/*you comparison rules*/){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thus when you read a data from UI you create Employee instance object (or a collection of objects if there is a list of users on your page)

2. **Fetch the user data from database**. You have to implement the data fetching code depending on what database you're using. If it is an SQL or no-SQL database. What particular database vendor you're using and so on.

When you fetch data from the database you build another Employee isntance using that fetched data

3. **Compare objects from different sources**. Use your overriden `equals()` method.

Comment: You should always override both `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)`. And let the IDE help you.